# retrieve voucher codes from html

Tags: javascript

I'm a Email Developer and I have used a voucher tool to generate some codes.
The problem is that the voucher tool is really bad and allows only 5 codes in every page in the interface of the tool so to get a 1000 codes I have to go to lots of pages and copy and paste the code into excel sheet.

I don't use JavaScript with my work so if you can help me with some code that I can write in the console to get all the codes from HTML instead of manually copy pasting them would be great

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
                    <td id="tblEVoucherName" class="sorting_1 mystyle">bbv0041A953</td>
                    <td>£10.00</td>
                    <td>£75.00</td>
                    <td>30/09/2019 04:02 PM</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

<tr role="row" class="odd">
                    <td id="tblEVoucherName" class="sorting_1">bbv008995E5</td>
                    <td>£10.00</td>
                    <td>£75.00</td>
                    <td>30/09/2019 04:02 PM</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd">
                    <td id="tblEVoucherName" class="sorting_1">bbv0276EA99</td>
                    <td>£10.00</td>
                    <td>£75.00</td>
                    <td>30/09/2019 04:02 PM</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
```

I've tried this document.getElementById("tblEVoucherName") but I only get one code

Also I have tried getElementByClassname and it doesn't work

document.getElementsByClassName('sorting_1')

HTMLCollection(10) [td#tblEVoucherName.sorting_1.mystyle, td#tblEVoucherName.sorting_1, td#tblEVoucherName.sorting_1, td#tblEVoucherName.sorting_1, td#tblEVoucherName.sorting_1, td#tblEVoucherName.sorting_1, td#tblEVoucherName.sorting_1, td#tblEVoucherName.sorting_1, td#tblEVoucherName.sorting_1, td#tblEVoucherName.sorting_1, tblEVoucherName: td#tblEVoucherName.sorting_1.mystyle]

This is the HTML for the pages

```
 <li class="paginate_button previous" id="eVoucherTable_previous"><a href="#" aria-controls="eVoucherTable" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a></li>
 <li class="paginate_button previous" id="eVoucherTable_previous"><a href="#" aria-controls="eVoucherTable" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a></li>
 <li class="paginate_button previous" id="eVoucherTable_previous"><a href="#" aria-controls="eVoucherTable" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0">3</a></li>
 <li class="paginate_button previous" id="eVoucherTable_previous"><a href="#" aria-controls="eVoucherTable" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0">4</a></li>
```

Comment: Ids need to be unique in html, so you should fix that. Also use getElementsByClassName to find all elements with class "sorting_1" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: please change the id names. id name should be unique . here is the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to the bottom of your html page:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>

var len = $(".sorting_1").length;

for(var i=0;i<len;i++){

console.log($(".sorting_1").eq(i).text());
}


</script>
```

Comment: No need for jQuery here, nor the op has asked to use one, just use getElementsByClassName instead

Comment: if I do that I only get the ones from the first page

Comment: say on page 2, you will be having a class 'sorting_2', right?

Comment: it only changes the page number index, the html classes are the same for the codes

Comment: a bit confusion..... just let me know, you have different html pages? or using pagination?